# Running Excel automation locally or on server

Tags: excel, vba, windows-server-2008

Wanted some opinions on which method is a better practice. We have a sales report that MUST be generated in a very specific format (down to the row colors and fonts).

I already have written a macro which pulls from our database and populates the entire workbook in about 15 seconds. The question is how should it be populated?

1) Process server-side: Users initiate the request on the intranet page. ASP.NET opens the workbook template, executes the macro and serves back the final sheet.

2) Process locally: Users download the blank template, run from their desktops which automatically connect to the database.

I like the first one because I can enforce the template, timing, users, and security of the data. But is running Excel automation on an internet web server recommended? I like the second option, but I'm afraid of losing standardization as template sheets begin floating around the company.

Comment: Running Excel on a web server will bring no end of misery into your life.

Comment: Option 2: Your users can generate the report locally, but store the template sheet on the server and have the report-generating macro download the template from the server as part of the process. If you need, have some information stored on the template which gets checked by the macro to ensure everone is using the most-current version.

Comment: Is it possible to have Excel read a macro script from a text file? This way I could maintain the latest code in a single location.

Comment: You could store the actual workbook on the server, and have the users open it directly from a link. Or put all the report-generating code in an add-in which gets loaded from the server by the workbook when the end-user opens it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for 1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for server side:

I highly.. HIGHLY.. recommend checking out the OpenOffice/LibreOffice XML format for spread sheets.

You can use the localc binary in headless mode to convert the XML file to XLSX or what have you.  I use it to create PDF files instead of using ReportLab.

Alternatively here are some other projects that attempt to write to Microsoft formats directly:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd
  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

As for client side:

If you expect the user to be only using Excel and not any other spreadsheet software then go ahead and use an ODBC data source.  ODBC will have to be configured per user unless you use some fun VBScript to pull the data from an HTTP server every time it is loaded.  There is also the option of making an XLS spreadsheet that simply holds the data and including it into an XLS document as well which would be both a server and client XLS requirement.

Go for server side.  Makes information simple to archive and share and will most likely be multi-platform as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use your first option, then you want to avoid using VBA on an installed instance of Excel on the server. This is extremely resource intensive and does not scale well. Instead, if you are writing ASP.NET code, then you should try using the Microsoft Office Interop functionality that is built into the .NET framework. It should possible to adapt your existing VBA code to run under ASP.NET with some changes, but you will have a much more reliable product in the end.

[Example Code](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel)

However, as @whardier points out in his response, if this were for a large scale or public site, the suggestions he makes would be much more suitable and would scale much further.

Comment: I was thinking about this as well, but wasn't sure if I was ultimately going to alleviate server overhead running it in ASP.NET vs an instance of Excel.